# CucumberReports show retried tests

Tags: java, cucumber

I'm using TestNG IRetryAnalyzer to retry my scenarios.

```
public class RetryFailedTestCases implements IRetryAnalyzer {
    private static final int maxRetryCount = 1;

    private ThreadLocal<Integer> retryCount = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> 0);
    private ThreadLocal<String> lastScenario = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @Override
    public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
        Object[] parameters = result.getParameters();
        String currentScenario = null;
        if (parameters.length > 0 && parameters[0] instanceof PickleWrapper) {
            PickleWrapper pickle = (PickleWrapper) parameters[0];
            currentScenario = pickle.getPickle().getUri() + pickle.getPickle().getName();

            if (!currentScenario.equals(lastScenario.get())) {
                retryCount.set(0); 
                lastScenario.set(currentScenario);
            }
        }

        if (retryCount.get() < maxRetryCount) {
            retryCount.set(retryCount.get() + 1);
            System.out.println("!RETRY TEST: " + currentScenario);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And it all works fine, except that CucumberReports shows the failed result even if retry was PASSED.

```
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "classpath:features",
        glue = "com.dope.bdd",
        tags =  "@smoke",
        plugin = {
                "pretty",
                "html:reports/tests/cucumber/cucumber-pretty.html",
                "testng:reports/tests/cucumber/testng/cucumber.xml",
                "json:reports/tests/cucumber/json/cucumberTestReport.json"
        }
)
public class CucumberRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests { ...
```

How to make CucumberReports to show the retried result? Is there a way to control that from code for example?